# How to generate Intelligent Mail® Barcode (OneCode) via PHP

Tags: php, generator, barcode, usps

I have a request to provide CASS certificated addresses on a PDF document. This involves using a certified mailing address, and needs to be printed using the [barcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Mail_barcode).

How can I generate such a barcode? Might exists PHP libraries that already does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USPS has [libraries and helper code](https://ribbs.usps.gov/onecodesolution/download.cfm) you can download for all major platforms.  They don't have a PHP class, but you could `exec` or `system` out to the OS to generate the code.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to remember is that certification on a CASS-certified address expires after 95 days.  This means that you will need to recertify your (or your client's) database about every three months on a minimum.  Without that, you can't generate an IMB (intelligent mail barcode) because the IMB is composed of a number of elements including the 12-digit delivery point barcode.

I would imagine that you already have a place to certify your addresses, but for those who read this Stack Overflow question and don't have certified and standardized addresses, you can do a Google search and find a handful of providers.

In the interest of full disclosure, I'm the founder of SmartyStreets.  We offer [address verification and validation](http://www.smartystreets.com/) which gives back the 12-digit delivery point barcode from which the IMB is derived.  I would be happy to personally answer any additional codes you have related to address verification and standardization.

Answer (score 5):

The [tc-lib-barcode](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode) (https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode) PHP software library allows you to generate "IMB - Intelligent Mail Barcode - Onecode - USPS-B-3200" barcodes.

The source code is fully PSR-2 compliant and can be easily added to your PHP projects using [Composer](https://packagist.org/packages/tecnick.com/tc-lib-barcode).

The original code has been ported and refactored from [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) and already used in billions of documents.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple approaches from some of the other answers here and they didn't work for me:

1. The official libraries and helper code from the USPS aren't very clear. They're also platform dependent and seem to be most useful if you're planning to do a mail merge in Excel or some other desktop app. If you're trying to integrate with a PHP web app, I'm not sure this is a very good route.
2. It seems like [tc-lib-barcode](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode) doesn't use the official USPS font. It doesn't look correct when compared side-by-side and when I tried validating a barcode using [this tool](https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/), it failed.

I ended up using [this IMB Converter class](https://gist.github.com/seratne/2d875facb16441d349bc8c0ddad9620c) instead. You can download the [USPS official font USPSIMBStandard](https://ribbs.usps.gov/onecodesolution/download.cfm) and then display your bar code hash using the font (it should be in the fonts/scalable/trueType folder). To generate a bar code hash, you first need to generate a code. This is outlined on page 2 of [this PDF from the USPS](https://about.usps.com/election-mail/steps-to-creating-intelligent-mail-barcode.pdf). Once you have a code (e.g. 0027012345678955555590210), you can run it through the converter class:

```
$barcode = IMB::Convert('0027012345678955555590210');
```

This returns TFDAAFAADDTDDFDFDATADDDATDAFAFDATADADADFATAFAFAFDADATFTFDAFDTADDT. You can then inject this directly into a PDF using the USPSIMBStandard font, or display it in HTML.

```
<p style="font-family:'USPSIMBStandard'; color:#000; font-size: 100px;"><?php echo $barcode; ?></p>
```

[image: USPS Bar Code Example]

When generating bar code hashes, it's unclear how accurate IMB::Convert is in comparison to the official USPS encoder. I tested a few combinations and they all seem to match. If you do want to use the official USPS encoder, you can run it on the command line like this:

```
$ IMBshell 0027012345678955555590210
```